# Assigning values to a struct member without using the members name in c?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, pointer-to-member

I have a structure and what I would like to do is to assign values to its members using a for loop. That way I do not have to use the members name. Because the structure is long and i do not want 20 lines of `p_struct->member_name` etc. What I have so far is below, but i am not sure if i am going in the right direction.
In header file:

```
typedef struct {
 int x;
 char ch;
  ...
  ...
}data;
data g_data;
```

in .c file...

```
data *p_data;
p_data = &(g_data.x)
for(i=0 till struct_elements) {
    *p_data = (some value);
    p_data++; //next member
}
```

Comment: would it help if i use #pragma pack?

Comment: Far uglier than 20 lines of p_struct->member_name is any solution that obfuscates what your code is doing. If the initialization bothers you so much, wrap it in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid C. But what would be valid C is to make constant table of the types and offsets of each member, and use that in your loop:

```
struct struct_def {
    int typecode;
    size_t offset;
};

static const struct struct_def mystruct_def[] = {
    { TYPE_INT, offsetof(struct mystruct, x) },
    { TYPE_CHAR, offsetof(struct mystruct, y) },
    /* ... */
    { TYPE_NONE, 0 }
};
```

Then you could access the member `x` as `*(int *)((char *)foo + mystruct_def[0].offset)`.

This is just an example; real world usage would probably be a bit more elaborate...

Answer (score 1):

You're not, p_data is a pointer to data, p_data++ will move it sizeof (data) bytes up, which will not be the next member, but outside your structure. Also, since members are of different types, the method will not work even if that problem would have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a readability problem that you are trying to solve, then you should consider using a struct initializer:

```
typedef struct { int a,b,c,d,e } data; 

data g_data[10];
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
 data t={i,i*2,i*3,i*4,i*5 }; /* non-constant initializers are supported with C99, C++, GNU-C or MSVC..*/
 g_data[i]=t; /* the optimizer will turn this into direct stores.. */
}
```

If you are using gcc (or a C99 compiler, thank's Dietrich Epp for the reminder), then you can even write:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
 g_data[i]=(data){i,i*2,i*3,i*4,i*5 }; 
}
```

Comment: This is standard C99, so it works practically everywhere these days (with the exception of MSVC).